# ExtJs Form.submit() response does not have responses json body

Tags: json, file, extjs, upload, submit

I have form like

```
    items: [{
        xtype: 'form',
        itemId: 'form',
        bodyPadding: 5,
        url: 'upload',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
            name: 'file',
            fieldLabel: 'label',
            emptyText: 'enter',
            labelWidth: 60,
            width: 590,
            msgTarget: 'side',
            allowBlank: false,
            buttonText: 'browse'
        }],
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'upload',
                itemId: 'loadButton'
            }]
    }]
```

and click handler

```
onLoadBtn: function (button) {
    var form = button.up('form').getForm(),
    if (form.isValid()) {
        form.submit({
            scope: this,
            submitEmptyText: false,
            fileupload:true,
            success: function (form, action) {
                var response = Ext.JSON.decode(action.response.responseText, true);
                if (response.success) {
                    Ext.Msg.show({
                        title: 'success',
                        msg: response.message,
                        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                        icon: Ext.Msg.INFO
                    });
                } else {
                    this.error(response.message);
                }
            },
            failure: function (form, action) {
                var response = Ext.JSON.decode(action.response.responseText, true);
                this.error(response.message);
            },
        });
    }
},
```

Endpoint from server side return response with json body

```
{"success" : "true", "message" : "Success"}
```

, but in browser network response body is empty.

Request have header

```
Accept : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
```

If i change it to

```
Accept : 'application/json'
```

and resend request, i got a response with right json body.

Any ideas, what need to change in the form or handler, so that change the accept header?

Comment: What about "standardSubmit: true" will it help?

Comment: Thanks! Response have json body now, but result of the request is opened new tab with json and success or failure methods are not called.

Comment: Looks like the 'accept' header is set by browser and it is impossible to change it from from.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Responses body has been disabled by response header

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

Thanks!